# Trying to replace a data from specific child (Firebase Database)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to replace kids/[id]/kidLimit/[new data]

So what I do is I make a spinner with kidName data, then with the selected item from that spinner I want to replace the data of kidLimit (with the same parent as the selected item from the spinner).

The first thing I do is to find the unique key of the selected item, then go to the kidLimit with that unique key to then use the setValue() method.

```
public class setLimit extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference db;
    private EditText etLimit;
    private Button btnSetLimit;
    private Spinner kidSpinner;
    private String kidKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_limit);

        etLimit = findViewById(R.id.et_limit);
        btnSetLimit = findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
        kidSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_kid);

        //PUTTING STRING LIST FROM FIREBASE TO SPINNER DROPDOWN STARTS HERE

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("kids");
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<String> kid = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String kidName = dataSnapshot1.child("kidName").getValue(String.class);
                    kid.add(kidName);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> kidNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(setLimit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kid);
                kidNameAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                kidSpinner.setAdapter(kidNameAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //ENDS HERE

        //ONCLICKLISTENER

        btnSetLimit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                findId();

                String newLimit = etLimit.getText().toString().trim();
                db.child(kidKey).child("kidLimit").setValue(newLimit);
            }
        });
    }

    //FINDING KEY FROM THE SELECTED SPINNER ITEM

    public void findId(){

        String kidName = kidSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("kids");
        db.orderByChild("kidName").equalTo(kidName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    kidKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

So basically what I did was using the snapshot inside the onclick method to find the key. But when I check them on the log, it showed that the kidkey variable is null the first time I press the button, but after that it's not null anymore.

What can I to do so when I press the button, I can go to a specific child to replace it's data without getting any null pointer exception?

Here's the database that I use
[image: Database Used]

Comment: FYI you can use the {} button in the editor to select and format an entire block of code (don't just indent the first line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
btnSetLimit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findId();

            String newLimit = etLimit.getText().toString().trim();
            db.child(kidKey).child("kidLimit").setValue(newLimit);
        }
    });
```

`findId();` is executed but you don't know when it will finish, so after that method is executed and waiting for data, this line

```
db.child(kidKey).child("kidLimit").setValue(newLimit);
```

will have kidKey with a null value because it has not been pulled yet from the database, so instead, you should move your code to the `onDataChange()` or make a new callback when all the asynchronous process finishes

```
btnSetLimit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            findId();
        }
    });

public void findId(){

    String kidName = kidSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String newLimit = etLimit.getText().toString().trim();

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("kids");
    db.orderByChild("kidName").equalTo(kidName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                kidKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
            }


            db.child(kidKey).child("kidLimit").setValue(newLimit);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: exactly what I've thought but I didn't really have a clue on how and where to move the code before. lol